# C++ TCP server receives data multiple times

Tags: c++, server, tcp

[image: Output] The output when I send hello.

I'm coding a C++ TCP server and I'm using a while loop to continuously get data but I think it's accepting the same thing and prints a bit of the thing that it's meant to output.

```cpp
 while (true) 
        {
            char buffer[5];
            if (recv(clisoc, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) {
               
                string abc = (string)buffer;
           
             
                cout << abc.substr(0, sizeof(buffer));          
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: *These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error
       occurred.  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the
       error.* Where do you check the returned value?

Comment: `recv` returns the amount of bytes received. It's not a boolean. It could return -1, which in this case would execute the `if` statement's code.

Comment: `(string)buffer` expects the contents of `buffer` to be nul-terminated, but there's no reason to believe they are. `sizeof(buffer)` is unrelated to the number of bytes `recv` actually stored in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You only tested the return value of `recv` to see if it didn't detect a normal close, so none of your subsequent code has any idea how much data you received. Likely, you are receiving data once but printing it twice. You cannot cast arbitrary data to a `string`, that is legal only for a pointer to an actual string.

Comment: Not so much "ignored" as "failed to capture the return value of" the `recv()` call.

Comment: And he only tested the return value of `recv()` to see if it wasn't zero. -1 isn't a success. And there is no 'likely' about it. It is certain.